# Replace google map api default info window with custom

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps-api

When you click on a location inside the map using the Google Maps API it displays an info window with the name, address, and link to view it on Google Maps.

[image]

Is there a way to override this event and supply it with my own data & styles?

So far I added an onClick listener that looks for events with a placeId property, grabs data for that place, and displays it in an InfoWindow component.

However, this doesn't prevent the default window from opening. It still opens and then gets covered by mine. Works but not exactly what I'm hoping to accomplish.

I either want to completely prevent the default one from showing, OR, apply my changes directly to it and not need to have this separate event handler.

```
async function handleOnClick(event) {
    setContent(undefined);
    const latitude = event.latLng.lat();
    const longitude = event.latLng.lng();

    if (event.placeId) {
      const request = {
        placeId: event.placeId,
        fields: ['name', 'formatted_address', 'place_id', 'geometry', 'photo'],
      };

      const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      placesService.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          const info = (
            <InfoWindow
              position={{
                lat: place?.geometry?.location?.lat(),
                lng: place?.geometry?.location?.lng(),
              }}
              onCloseClick={() => setContent(undefined)}
            >
              <div>
                <h3>{place.name}</h3>
                <div className='photo-gallery'>
                  {place?.photos.map((photo) => {
                    return <img className='photo' src={photo.getUrl()} />;
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            </InfoWindow>
          );

          setContent(info);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

I doing this in react with the @react-google-maps/api library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `event.stop()` method for POI click event to prevent the Info Window from showing while still processing the Place ID (EDITED)

There's an option on `MapOptions` called `clickableIcons` where you can set to `false`, which would disable the click capability on the default POI icons/markers.

Unfortunately, this would also disable the feature where you can have the `placeId` of the icon using the `map.addListener()`

What I would suggest is for you to **file a Feature Request** that would enable developers to modify the content of the default POIs when clicked. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

But since the Google Maps API currently does not have this feature, one workaround (Thanks to OPs comment), is to turn off the event with `event.stop` once you have the place ID on POI click.

Here's how it should work using the code OP provided:

Create an Info Window state hook to store the contents later on and generate the Component.

```
const [infoWindow, setInfoWindow] = React.useState(null);
```

Inside the onLoad callback definition, you check if the Place ID is available. Then if is true, you fire the `event.stop()` method to prevent the default Info Window from showing and proceed in processing the fetched Place ID with Places API Place Details and put those data on the custom Info Window you will render on the clicked POI icon.

```
const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
  map.addListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.placeId) {
      // once the check for Place ID is done, 
      // fire the event.stop() here to prevent the default Info Window from showing
      event.stop();
      
      // Proceed in processing the Place Details request
      // and create the custom Info Window based on the fetched data
      const request = {
        placeId: event.placeId,
        fields: [
          "name",
          "formatted_address",
          "place_id",
          "geometry",
          "photo",
        ],
      };

      const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      placesService.getDetails(request, (place, status) => {
        if (status === "OK") {
          // store the Info Window component inside a variable,
          // This will be put inside the Info Window state hook later.
          const info = (
            <InfoWindow
              position={{
                lat: place?.geometry?.location?.lat(),
                lng: place?.geometry?.location?.lng(),
              }}
              onCloseClick={() => setInfoWindow(null)}
            >
              <div>
                <h3>{place.name}</h3>
                <div className="photo-gallery">
                  {place?.photos.map((photo) => {
                    return <img className="photo" src={photo.getUrl()} />;
                  })}
                </div>
              </div>
            </InfoWindow>
          );
          // Update the Info Window state hook here.
          setInfoWindow(info);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Then you just put the `infoWindow` state hook inside the `GoogleMap` component to show the Info Window when the details are provided.

```
return isLoaded ? (
  <GoogleMap
    mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
    center={center}
    zoom={15}
    onLoad={onLoad}
    onUnmount={onUnmount}
  >
    {infoWindow ? infoWindow : null}
  </GoogleMap>
) : (
  <></>
);
```

After all that, it should look something like this:

[image]

Here's a proof of concept code sandbox that you can try and play around: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/poi-click-infowindow-tfxjjw

> NOTE: Use your own API KEY

Comment: Thanks for your input. The biggest problem I found is that it was hard to get it to target the right location with POIs turned off. But it did lead me to find this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-poi

You can call `event.stop()` and it prevents the default info window from showing. It would be nice to just edit the default info window's response but this gets the job done too.

Comment: That's great to hear! And I was not aware that we can just stop the default info window from showing. Is the place ID still being returned after doing so?

Comment: Yes because `clickableIcons` is still set to true. So you can click directly on the POI and then prevent the default info window.

Here's what I did:
Click on map and in Map's onClick function check for placeId in the event obj. If it has a placeId then stop the event from triggering the default info window.


`if (event.placeId) {
      event.stop();
     // logic to call placesService and create custom InfoWindow
}`

Comment: Alright, and thanks for the additional inputs. I'll play around with it and work on editing my answer.

Comment: @Lehi, the link that you've shared is correct. You can also check [IconMouseEvent interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#IconMouseEvent). A sample demo here: https://jsbin.com/yejuqoceku/edit?js,output